# Use Scrape automation on a website with URL that do not change

Tags: javascript, asp.net, node.js

I have a problem I am trying to scrape a site using the webscraper.io extention for chrome. It will not work because the URL doesn't change but does reset back to search input page if browser is refreshed.

I previously tried in nodeJs but the site has been redesigned and the URL never changes so I can not set the URL starting point for scraping in nodeJs. I looked in the network tab of the chrome console and found the form data with the correct selection (year, street name and similar name) but I don't know the full address.

here is an address and zip to try

**URL** http://hcad.org/property-search/real-property/real-property-search-by-address/

**Year and Address** 2016 Post Oak

Can someone please tell me how to manually put the address together?

Comment: Observing the Network tab in Chrome Devtools, it looks like the actual request is made for `http://public.hcad.org/records/SelectRecord.asp`, with some attached form data. I tried sending a request myself from Postman and it responded with an error page, but that should be a step in the right direction.

Comment: @ChemicalRocketeer not sure why you got the error, i am getting proper response. Maybe you forgot adding stuff like `User-Agent` etc...

Comment: @georoot I did copy the headers from the devtools window, but I missed that I had to have Interceptor turned on for some of them to work. After some further testing I'm now getting a "Temporarily unavailable" error page, even though the actual page is still working normally.

Answer (score 0):

First let me answer why the **scraper** is not working, the idea of the website is that they post data to `/SelectRecord.asp` which in turns returns js containing data which they append to dom and you see the result. Unluckily that type of behaviour is specific to this site.

### How to scrape such sites

#### Method 1

Use `selinium` to post form data and scrape results from the DOM. This is longer process but reliable in case of complex web applications.

#### Method 2

Taking your existing site into consideration, i notice that the post parameters on the site are

```
TaxYear=2016
stnum
stname=Post+Oak
searchtype=str
```

The above i got from the query you gave above. And the result is something like

```
....
<td align="left" valign="center" nowrap>111 POST OAK # 286</td>
<td valign="center">77024</td>
<td valign="center">0</td>
<td valign="center">$84,840</td>
<td valign="center">$84,840</td>
....
```

I have just pasted a part of the complete code.

Now all you have to do is make a `curl` request with params of your choice and scrape off the XML which is much more simpler.

Comment: I'll try the selenium method and Method 2...I don't have experience with selenium....I am using windows machine so if you have any pointers please post